# Java printing input of a vector and deleting vector with specific number

Tags: java, vector

I have a class `Runner`  that has a `name`,`startnr`, `weight` and `age`. I should be able to create and print Runner.

```
public class Runner {
    private String name;
    private int startnr;
    private int weight;
    private int age;

    public Runner(String name, int startnr, int weight, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.startnr = startnr;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.age = age;
        print();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        createRunner();
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Startnr: " + startnr);
        System.out.println("Weight: " + weight);
        System.out.println("Age " + age);
    }

    public static void createRunner(){
        Runner One = new Runner("Two", 0,76,24);
        Runner Two = new Runner("One", 1, 80, 21);
    }
}
```

Then I have a class `ControlRunner` which should allow to manage the runners, i.e.

- runners can be read in (with a scanner)
- every runner gets a distinct `startnr`
- the runners should be inside a `Vector`
- it should be possible to print all the runners out
- it should be possible to delete a runner with a specific startnr

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

public class ControlRunner {

    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static int startnr = 1;
    private static Vector v;
    private static String output, name;
    private static int weight, age;

    static Runner myrunner;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        createLaeufer();
    }

    public static void createLaeufer(){

        System.out.println("Write the amount of runners you want to create");

        Vector<Runner> vector = new Vector<>();

        int amount = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {

            System.out.println("Write the name of the runner: ");
            name = sc.next();

            System.out.println("Write the weight of the runner: ");
            weight = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Write the age of the runner: ");
            age = sc.nextInt();

            myrunner = new Runner(name, startnr, weight, age);
            vector.add(myrunner);
            // v.forEach(Runner -> myrunner.print());
            startnr++;

        }

        System.out.println("Do you want to print all runners? (Y/N) ");
        output = sc.next();
        if (output.equals("Y")) {
            vector.forEach(Runner -> myrunner.print());
        } else {
            return;
        }


        System.out.println("Do you want to delete a runner? (Y/N) ");
        String delete = sc.next();
        if (delete.equals("Y")){
            System.out.print("Write the starting number: ");
            int nummer = sc.nextInt();
            vector.remove(nummer - 1);
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that I don't know how to print all the runners through the vector. (Right now, it only prints one). Another problem is that it terminates after deleting a runner because the else just gives a `return`. (I don't think the structure is good because I'm new to Java). How can I improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this part you don't use your vector and just printing the last data.

```
System.out.println("Do you want to print all runners? (Y/N) ");
output = sc.next();
if (output.equals("Y")){
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Startnr: enter code enter code herehere" + (startnr - 1));
    System.out.println("Weight: " + weight);
    System.out.println("Age " + age);
} else {
    return;
}
```

If you want to print all vector info you need something like this:

```
v.forEach(runner -> runner.print())
```

Also you create vector inside cycle, so you create vector for each runner and then just forget about it. I think you need to create vector before the cycle of creation runners.

Comment: The 'print' in the foreach doesn't work. (Cannot resolve symbol) and where exactly do I have to create vectors then?

Comment: @PoliticsStudent, you shouldn't create it inside the runner creation cycle. For example, right before your for cycle.

Comment: @PoliticsStudent, runner.print() doesn't work, because you don't specify Vector type, I think. Try *Vector<Runner> vector = new Vector<>()*.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. Look at my edited post (I tried to applied the change)

Comment: @PoliticsStudent, you need to change this line that way: vector.forEach(runner -> runner.print());

Comment: @PoliticsStudent, also you need put out of cycle code that prints info

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now, but what do you mean with I need to put out of cycle?

Comment: @PoliticsStudent, you have a for loop in which you receive information, create a runner and put it in a vector. Also after that, in the same loop, you display *"Do you want to delete a runner? (Y / N)"* dialog. Thus, if you have only 1 runner, then everything will be fine. But if you have at least 2 runners, then after creating the first you will have a dialog and it will display your first runner. After creating the second runner, you will again have this dialog that displays information of the two runners.

Comment: @PoliticsStudent, This is a little illogical and I would put this piece of code out of cycles and place after it. But if you wanted to do so, then this is quite normal.

Comment: I changed the code again (see edited post), but it prints the stored element of the vector twice. (So the first stored element isn't shown)

Comment: @PoliticsStudent, you change forEach line again:-). *vector.forEach()* use lambda expresion as parameter. Maybe you should read about it. The value before "->" must match with value before *.print()*. Because other way you just twice use myRunner value.